# What different between marked objects with arrow in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, prototype

I've a javascript object, when I log object in console, in object properties I've 2 type marked with arrow in picture.

What's different between types?

[image: javascript different type color]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` is a data property (with the value `36`), while the `parent` is an [accessor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description). To get it's value (that is not yet displayed), a getter would need to be evaluated (you can do so by clicking on the `(...)`), as the tooltip explains.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, what means about **accessor property**? can you help me for this?

Comment: @Varooneh I added a link to MDN. I was looking at the devtools documentation first, but there's nothing relevant in there.